# Working/Business/Calendar day to be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

I tried to find the possible rule on the Internet but couldn't.

So, do I have to capitalize such words as business or working or calendar when referring to a day in a document?
For ex.:

> Within five (5) **Working days** from the date of signing the relevant Documentation in the amount of ... for arranging financing of each Contractor.

> Within five (5) **Calendar days** after the end of the quarter.

Thank you!

Comment: Oh no; please don't do this. It's Super Annoying to read Sentences that Capitalize every Other word, especially Ordinary Words like Calendar or Days. See what I mean? :) There are some exceptions to this, of course, but you'll know when you're in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, "working days" (etc) is a common phrase and does not need to be capitalized.

Legal contracts are funny things and have their own rules a lot of the time. In the text you quoted, "Documentation" and "Contractor" are not *usually* proper nouns and would not *usually* be capitalized, but they are in this document because they were previously defined as referring to proper nouns, for example:

> Joe Schmo Construction Corp., ACME Supply Corp., and A-1 Foundations Inc. (hereinafter referred to as "Contractor" or "Contractors")...